# C# Issue converting PHP Hex2bin

Tags: c#, php, asp.net-mvc

I've been battling with converting a simple PHP script from PHP to c#.

I've tried all variations of converting the code over with no luck.
the main issue I am having is the matching of the results when running my code results against the PHP output.

Essentially, I am trying to build the same function as the PHP hex2bin.

This all works perfectly well with simple inputs samples but for complex items, it breaks.

Here is the PHP script code block

**PHP:**

```
$challenge = "50F8358C3E894AC1868C6EF8303AC4F14E9831470C046D5F3DBABB2EB588979E";
$secret = "verysecretstring";
$plain = "test";

$hexchall =  **hex2bin($challenge)**

$crypt_secret = md5($hexchall . $secret, true);

RESULT:
crypt_secret = "25a41f897e548d1300d032ba36100d94"
```

C#:

```
     public static string MD5_string(string text)
    {
        byte[] asciiBytes = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);
        byte[] hashedBytes = MD5CryptoServiceProvider.Create().ComputeHash(asciiBytes);
        string hashedString = BitConverter.ToString(hashedBytes).Replace("-", "").ToLower();

        return hashedString;
    }



   public static string ConvertHextoASCII(String hexString)
    {
        try
        {
            string ascii = string.Empty;

            for (int i = 0; i < hexString.Length; i += 2)
            {
                String hs = string.Empty;

                hs = hexString.Substring(i, 2);
                uint decval = System.Convert.ToUInt32(hs, 16);
                char character = System.Convert.ToChar(decval);
                ascii += character;

            }

            return ascii;
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); }

        return string.Empty;
    }


    public static string Encrypt_Password()
    {

        //string plain, string challenge, string secret
        var password = "test";
        var challenge = "50F8358C3E894AC1868C6EF8303AC4F14E9831470C046D5F3DBABB2EB588979E";

        var secret = "verysecretstring";

        var hex4 = ConvertHextoASCII(challenge);
        var crypt_secret4 = MD5_string(string.Concat(hex4, secret));
  }
```

I have tried plenty of solutions that I found on stack overflow, with no luck. even though I get the same bytes as the PHP from my C# code, I don't think the binary string conversion is keeping all characters.

Please, can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include your c# code and output, and we can help you from there

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto sorry, thought It went through . its up now.